# Static global settings class with serializing

Tags: c#, wpf, configuration

I have a class that is used for serializing and deserializing global application variables. I would like to know if there is anything that I can improve. I know I could inject a dependency to support multiple different serializing formats, but that is not my concern. I would especially want to know if my locking does anything since I am not very proficient in locking.

`CurrentLanguage` and `PointsCount` are the data that I serialize.

```
public static class GlobalSettings
{
    private static CultureInfo _currentLanguage;
    public static CultureInfo CurrentLanguage
    {
        get { lock (Sync) return _currentLanguage; }
        set { lock (Sync) _currentLanguage = value; }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<CultureInfo> AllLanguages => new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("pl-PL")
    };

    public static string DbPath => Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Data.db");

    private static int _pointsCount;
    public static int PointsCount
    {
        get { lock (Sync) return _pointsCount; }
        set { lock (Sync) _pointsCount = value; }
    }

    public static bool LoadedSuccessfully = true;
    public static Exception LoadedWithException = null;

    private static bool _isLoaded;
    private static readonly object Sync = new object();
    private static readonly string SettingsFilePath;

    static GlobalSettings()
    {
        var settingsRelativeFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SettingsRelativeFilePath"];
        SettingsFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, settingsRelativeFilePath);
    }

    public static void Save()
    {
        lock (Sync)
        {
            if (!_isLoaded)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Load settings first");

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GlobalSettingsStorage));

            using (var file = File.Create(SettingsFilePath))
            {
                var settings = new GlobalSettingsStorage
                {
                    CurrentLanguageShortName = CurrentLanguage.Name,
                    PointsCount = PointsCount
                };

                serializer.Serialize(file, settings);
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool TryLoad()
    {
        lock (Sync)
        {
            try
            {
                var fileExists = File.Exists(SettingsFilePath);

                var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GlobalSettingsStorage));
                using (var reader = File.Open(SettingsFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    GlobalSettingsStorage settings = null;
                    if (!fileExists)
                    {
                        settings = new GlobalSettingsStorage();
                        deserializer.Serialize(reader, settings);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        settings = (GlobalSettingsStorage)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    }

                    _currentLanguage = new CultureInfo(settings.CurrentLanguageShortName);
                    _pointsCount = settings.PointsCount;
                }

                _isLoaded = true;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex) when (ex.InnerException is XmlException)
            {
                LoadedSuccessfully = false;
                LoadedWithException = new SettingsLoadingException("XML settings file corrupted", ex);
                return false;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                LoadedSuccessfully = false;
                LoadedWithException = new SettingsLoadingException("You do not have access to the settings file.", ex);
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (ex is PathTooLongException || ex is DirectoryNotFoundException || ex is IOException)
            {
                LoadedSuccessfully = false;
                LoadedWithException = new SettingsLoadingException("Failed to load settings file", ex);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public sealed class GlobalSettingsStorage
{
    public string CurrentLanguageShortName { get; set; }
    public int PointsCount { get; set; }

    public GlobalSettingsStorage()
    {
        CurrentLanguageShortName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultLanguage"];
        PointsCount = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultPointsCount"]);
    }
}
```

I have property `LoadedSuccessfully`, because in WPF I want to show a user information if settings were not properly loaded and I show it as a popup.

```
public async void OnDialogHostLoaded()
{
    if (!GlobalSettings.LoadedSuccessfully)
    {
        var ex = GlobalSettings.LoadedWithException;
        var message = string.Join(": ", ex.Message, ex.InnerException?.Message);
        var popup = new PopupBoxView
        {
            DataContext = new PopupBoxViewModel(PopupBoxType.Ok, message, true)
        };

        NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Fatal(ex);
        await DialogHost.Show(popup, "RootHost");
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> public static int PointsCount
> {
>     get { lock (Sync) return _pointsCount; }
>     set { lock (Sync) _pointsCount = value; }
> }
> ```

I wonder why this property has a `public` setter? Is there a scenario where setting this form the *outside* would make sense?

---

Other things...

I like your exceptions. They clearly tell me what went wrong so I would instantly know how to fix that. You even have created a custom one `SettingsLoadingException`, kudos!

I would however change how you handle this:

> ```
> public static bool LoadedSuccessfully = true;
> ```

Make it `false` by default and set it to `true` only once when `TryLoad` succeeded. Currently you set it three time to `false` instead.

You could also flip the logic with `return true` and do it onyl once before the first `catch`, this is, inside the `try` and do `return false` only once at the end of the method.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show how you actually call `TryLoad()`. So with that in mind here are some comments:

> ```
> public static bool LoadedSuccessfully = true;
> public static Exception LoadedWithException = null;
>
> private static bool _isLoaded;
> ```

What is the difference between `LoadedSuccessfully` and `_isLoaded`? The one is initially set to true, while the other is set to false, but they both indicate if the load was successful or not. I think you can remove one of them.

Another issue is that `LoadedSuccessfully` and `LoadedWithException` are public settable. If they are of any use - see next comment - I would change them to private settable properties instead.

These three fields have only meaning for the state of the object in the load process, because - as I read `OnDialogHostLoaded()` - you close the application in a following step in the load process, if loading the settings went wrong. In other words: you probably don't have a running application with `GlobalSettings.LoadedSuccessfully = false`. I think, I would remove these fields and reconsider the load process so you close the application immediately if `TryLoad()` fails like:

```
void OnLoad() // Or what ever you call it
{
  try
  {
    GlobalSettings.Load();
  }
  catch (SettingsLoadingException ex)
  {
    // TODO: log and exit application
    // Maybe fire an event to let the main app notify user via UI
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // TODO: log and exit application
    // Maybe fire an event to let the main app notify user via UI
  }
}
```

Here `TryLoad()` is renamed to just `Load()` because it doesn't return a boolean but only throws on failure:

```
public static void Load()
{
  lock (Sync)
  {
    try
    {
      var fileExists = File.Exists(SettingsFilePath);

      var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GlobalSettingsStorage));
      using (var reader = File.Open(SettingsFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
      {
        GlobalSettingsStorage settings = null;
        if (!fileExists)
        {
          settings = new GlobalSettingsStorage();
          deserializer.Serialize(reader, settings);
        }
        else
        {
          settings = (GlobalSettingsStorage)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        _currentLanguage = new CultureInfo(settings.CurrentLanguageShortName);
        _pointsCount = settings.PointsCount;
      }
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex) when (ex.InnerException is XmlException)
    {
      throw new SettingsLoadingException("XML settings file corrupted", ex);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
      throw new SettingsLoadingException("You do not have access to the settings file.", ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (ex is PathTooLongException || ex is DirectoryNotFoundException || ex is IOException)
    {
      throw new SettingsLoadingException("Failed to load settings file", ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      throw new SettingsLoadingException("General exception occured", ex);
    }
  }
}
```

I've added a general catch clause to catch all unknown exceptions by, so that you can rethrow a `SettingsLoadeingException` for them as well.

---

I imagine that the reason for having `LoadedSuccessfylly` is that you postpone handling a possible failure in `GlobalSettings.TryLoad()` to `OnDialogHostLoaded()`. IMO you handle the settings failure in the wrong place: what have loading the settings to do with loading the "dialog host"?

---

You only catch specific exceptions. What happens to more general exceptions or special exceptions that don't meet the conditions in your catch clauses?

---

> ```
>         GlobalSettingsStorage settings = null;
>         if (!fileExists)
>         {
>           settings = new GlobalSettingsStorage();
>           deserializer.Serialize(reader, settings);
>         }
>         else
> ```

Why is it necessary to save an empty settings file, if it doesn't exist when trying to load it? You somehow break the single responsibility principle here.